# How to navigate in react app from one component to another component, by taking the data from one component and displaying in another component

Tags: reactjs, navigation, react-router-dom, react-props

I have created a react app, in that app there are two components one is Profile.js and the another one is ViewProfile.js. The Profile component contains a table of details of emlployees,that includes a button named as viewprofile button in the table. By clicking the button it navigates to the ViewProfile component, which display the corresponding detail of the employee.

The above is my problem statement.

I have imported BrowserRouter ,routes,route and link from react-router-dom and routed the Profile componet as home component and I have given  the link  to viewprofile button as /viewprofile/:id.

I am able to view the profile component correctly and I am able to navigate to viewprofile component but I can't able to display the data of the corresponding  employee.

Answer (score -1):

In React applications, you can pass data from one component to another component and navigate between components using various techniques. One common approach is to use React Router for navigation and pass data through props or route parameters. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to achieve this:

#### Step 1: Set Up React Router

First, make sure you have React Router installed. If not, you can install it using npm or yarn:

```
npm install react-router-dom
# or
yarn add react-router-dom
```

#### Step 2: Create Routes

Set up your routes in your main `App.js` or `index.js` file. Define routes for your components using `Route` components from React Router. You can pass data through the `props` of the components.

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import ComponentOne from './ComponentOne';
import ComponentTwo from './ComponentTwo';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route path="/component-one" component={ComponentOne} />
      <Route path="/component-two/:data" component={ComponentTwo} />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

In this example, `ComponentOne` is rendered when the path is `/component-one`, and `ComponentTwo` is rendered when the path is `/component-two/:data`. `:data` is a route parameter that can be accessed in `ComponentTwo`.

#### Step 3: Pass Data and Navigate

In `ComponentOne`, you can have a button or an event handler that navigates to `ComponentTwo` and passes data through the route parameter.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const ComponentOne = () => {
  const dataToSend = 'Hello from Component One';

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Component One</h1>
      <Link to={`/component-two/${dataToSend}`}>
        <button>Go to Component Two</button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ComponentOne;
```

In `ComponentTwo`, you can access the data passed through the route parameter and display it.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const ComponentTwo = () => {
  const { data } = useParams();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Component Two</h1>
      <p>Data from Component One: {data}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ComponentTwo;
```

In this example, when you click the button in `ComponentOne`, it navigates to `ComponentTwo` and displays the data passed through the route parameter.

Remember, this is just one way to pass data and navigate between components. Depending on your application's complexity, you might explore other state management solutions like Context API or Redux.